# How to Query Firebase based on Multiple Equal to

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below firebase structure. From this I need to fetch data based on query `where Dstatus=ok and Drmoble=mobile no`

[image]

so far I have written this which is working for a single value only.How can I combine both

```
 mReferenceBooks.orderByChild("Drmoble").equalTo(mobile_no).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In firebase realtime database, their is no `AND` query, which means you can't do:

```
mReferenceBooks.orderByChild("Drmoble").equalTo(mobile_no).orderByChild("DStatus").equalTo("ok")
```

To solve this you can create another field that will contain both the `DStatus` and the `Drmoble`, for example:

```
randomId
     dstatus-drmoble : "01810000-ok"
```

Then you can use the following query:

```
mReferenceBooks.orderByChild("dstatus-drmoble").equalTo("01810000-ok").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```